# Explicit bivariate quadratic polynomials where Coppersmith is better than standard solver?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, computational-number-theory

http://www.numbertheory.org/pdfs/general_quadratic_solution.pdf gives a general method to solve quadratic bivariate diophantine equation while [Coppersmith introduced a method to solve bivariate polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith_method) which work provably and have been shown to break $RSA$ system if half of low significant bits of either $P$ or $Q$ are known.

The equation that comes out is $$(2^ku+v)(2^ku'+v')=PQ$$ where if we assume $v$ is known. Then $vv'\equiv PQ\bmod 2^k$ gives $v'$.

So we have a quadratic diophantine equation $$2^kuu'+(uv'+u'v)=\frac{PQ-vv'}{2^k}.$$

Why do I need Coppersmith's method to solve this? Can't a regular diophantine solver work here and so are there explicit polynomials where Coppersmith is better than standard solver in bivariate quadratic case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Partial answer about "regular diophantine solver".

Finding points on conics in general require integer factorization.

Several papers deal with points on $a x^2+b y^2=c z^2$
and they require factorization of $a,b,c$.

Another example is $x^2 - a y^2=n z^2$. Solving it
will compute the square root of $a$ modulo $n$.

Coppersmith method avoid factorization at the cost of small solutions.